# MUI Autocomplete using groupBy together with filterOptions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I use the MUI's Autocomplete component and group the options by `facility` using the `groupBy` property and sort the list with the `filterOptions` property. `groupBy` shows the facility name in the header, which is what I want. With `filterOptions` I sort by `name` (numeric value from small to large).

```js
<Autocomplete
  options={[
    {
        "name": "foo-1",
        "facility": "foo",
    },
    {
        "name": "foo-3",
        "facility": "foo",
    },
    {
        "name": "bar-2",
        "facility": "bar",
    }
  ]}
  groupBy={(option) => option.facility}
  filterOptions={(options, { inputValue }) => filterOptions(options, inputValue)}
  ...
/>
```

It can happen that two options with the same facility are not grouped together because of the `filterOptions` function. In that case it looks like this (this is what I want):

[image]

But this creates duplicate headers and therefore this warning is given in the console:

```
MUI: The options provided combined with the `groupBy` method of Autocomplete returns duplicated headers. 
You can solve the issue by sorting the options with the output of `groupBy`.
```

Is there a way to overcome this warning or do I just have to deal with it?